# Why all method in PHP Exception class are final?

Tags: php

I tried to override the `getMessage()` to give the return message a default value but failed because all method in PHP `Exception` class are final.

Now I am just curious about why it is. I know I can work it around by adding a proxy method.

Comment: `Why all method in PHP Exception class are final?` to prevent your from `override the getMessage()` , the question is , why you may need to do this ?

Comment: can you explain a bit more what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @hassan. To __give it a default value__ ?

Comment: Just set the message in the constructor.

Comment: [getMessage()](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php) `Returns the Exception message. `

Comment: as you see, it's only has one job , returns the exception message, the function job is to return, not to set

Comment: @lafor. Very nice solution! How could I not think about it.

Comment: you may write your own exception to be able to add new method to `set your default value` as you wish;

Comment: @hassan. That is the dumb way, see how `@lafor` would do.

Comment: i thought that you already knew that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are `final` to make sure they work in the exact same way in all inherited `class`es. A programmer will expect `getMessage` to work in the exact same way for all `class`es inherited directly or transitively from `Exception`. You can set the message in the constructor though, as you will be able to write your own constructor for your class.

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression that you want a pattern like this:

```
<?php

class UserNotFoundException extends \RuntimeException {
    const MESSAGE_TEMPLATE = 'Could not find the requested user: %s';

    public static function fromId($user_id) {
        $message = sprintf(self::MESSAGE_TEMPLATE, "ID=$user_id");
        return new self($message);

    }
    public static function fromName($name) {
        $message = sprintf(self::MESSAGE_TEMPLATE, "name=$name");
        return new self($message);
    }
}

try {
    throw UserNotFoundException::fromId(314);
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
try {
    throw UserNotFoundException::fromName('john');
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

```
Could not find the requested user: ID=314
Could not find the requested user: name=john
```

Tweak it to your exact needs. This is quite practical for reuse and does not risk interfering with the overall exception mechanism.

Answer (score -2):

Write your own Exception.

```
class MyException extends \Exception
{

}
```

Comment: You can't override final methods, that's the whole point of OP's question. He wants to know why.